# Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find logstash-input-jdbc-4.2.1 in any of the sources 9 (logstash,elasticsearch)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, jdbc, logstash

I am working with elasticsearch and im also trying to connect mysql with elasticsearch via logstash. I created the config file and when i run it i get the following error

```
Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find logstash-input-jdbc-4.2.1 in any of the sources
  materialize at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92
         map! at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:2446
  materialize at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85
        specs at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132
    specs_for at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177
requested_specs at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166
requested_specs at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18
        setup at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13
        setup at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/bundler-1.9.10/lib/bundler.rb:122
       setup! at C:/Users/esmer/E/ELK/logstash-5.5.1/lib/bootstrap/bundler.rb:67
       (root) at C:\Users\esmer\E\ELK\logstash-5.5.1\lib\bootstrap\environment.rb:67code here
```

the config file's code is below:

```
input {
jdbc {
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:80/temperature"
    jdbc_user => "admin1"
    jdbc_password => ""
    jdbc_driver_library => "c:\e\elk\logstash-5.5.1\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.43-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    statement => "SELECT * FROM temperature" 
    jdbc_paging_enabled => "true"
    jdbc_page_size => "50000"
  }
}

output {
  stdout {codec => rubydebug}
  elasticsearch {
      hosts => "localhost:9200"
      index => "temperature"
      document_type => "data"
    } 
}
```

Gemfile :

```
            # This is a Logstash generated Gemfile.
        # If you modify this file manually all comments and formatting will be lost.

        source "https://rubygems.org"
        gem "logstash-core", :path => "./logstash-core"
        gem "logstash-core-plugin-api", :path => "./logstash-core-plugin-api"
        gem "paquet", "~> 0.2.0"
        gem "ruby-progressbar", "~> 1.8.1"
        gem "builder", "~> 3.2.2"
        gem "file-dependencies", "0.1.6"
        gem "ci_reporter_rspec", "1.0.0", :group => :development
        gem "simplecov", :group => :development
        gem "tins", "1.6", :group => :development
        gem "rspec", "~> 3.1.0", :group => :development
        gem "logstash-devutils", :group => :development
        gem "benchmark-ips", :group => :development
        gem "octokit", "3.8.0", :group => :build
        gem "stud", "~> 0.0.22", :group => :build
        gem "fpm", "~> 1.3.3", :group => :build
        gem "rubyzip", "~> 1.1.7", :group => :build
        gem "gems", "~> 0.8.3", :group => :build
        gem "rack", "1.6.6"
        gem "rack-test", :require => "rack/test", :group => :development
        gem "flores", "~> 0.0.6", :group => :development
        gem "term-ansicolor", "~> 1.3.2", :group => :development
        gem "docker-api", "1.31.0", :group => :development
        gem "rest-client", "1.8.0", :group => :development
        gem "pleaserun", "~>0.0.28"
        gem "logstash-input-heartbeat"
        gem "logstash-codec-collectd"
        gem "logstash-output-xmpp"
        gem "logstash-codec-cef"
        gem "logstash-codec-dots"
        gem "logstash-codec-edn"
        gem "logstash-codec-edn_lines"
        gem "logstash-codec-fluent"
        gem "logstash-codec-es_bulk"
        gem "logstash-codec-graphite"
        gem "logstash-codec-json"
        gem "logstash-codec-json_lines"
        gem "logstash-codec-line"
        gem "logstash-codec-msgpack"
        gem "logstash-codec-multiline"
        gem "logstash-codec-netflow", "~> 3.4.0"
        gem "logstash-codec-plain"
        gem "logstash-codec-rubydebug"
        gem "logstash-filter-clone"
        gem "logstash-filter-csv"
        gem "logstash-filter-date"
        gem "logstash-filter-dns"
        gem "logstash-filter-drop"
        gem "logstash-filter-fingerprint"
        gem "logstash-filter-geoip", "~> 4.2.0"
        gem "logstash-filter-grok"
        gem "logstash-filter-json"
        gem "logstash-filter-kv"
        gem "logstash-filter-metrics"
        gem "logstash-filter-mutate"
        gem "logstash-filter-ruby"
        gem "logstash-filter-sleep"
        gem "logstash-filter-split"
        gem "logstash-filter-syslog_pri"
        gem "logstash-filter-throttle"
        gem "logstash-filter-urldecode"
        gem "logstash-filter-useragent", "~> 3.1.0"
        gem "logstash-filter-uuid"
        gem "logstash-filter-xml"
        gem "logstash-input-couchdb_changes"
        gem "logstash-input-elasticsearch"
        gem "logstash-input-exec"
        gem "logstash-input-file"
        gem "logstash-input-ganglia"
        gem "logstash-input-gelf"
        gem "logstash-input-generator"
        gem "logstash-input-graphite"
        gem "logstash-input-http"
        gem "logstash-input-http_poller"
        gem "logstash-input-imap"
        gem "logstash-input-irc"
        gem "logstash-input-jdbc"
        gem "logstash-input-log4j"
        gem "logstash-input-lumberjack"
        gem "logstash-input-pipe"
        gem "logstash-input-rabbitmq"
        gem "logstash-input-redis"
        gem "logstash-input-s3"
        gem "logstash-input-snmptrap"
        gem "logstash-input-sqs"
        gem "logstash-input-stdin"
        gem "logstash-input-syslog"
        gem "logstash-input-tcp", "~> 4.1.0"
        gem "logstash-input-twitter"
        gem "logstash-input-udp"
        gem "logstash-input-unix"
        gem "logstash-input-xmpp"
        gem "logstash-input-kafka", "~> 5"
        gem "logstash-input-beats", "~> 3.0", ">= 3.1.18"
        gem "logstash-output-cloudwatch"
        gem "logstash-output-csv"
        gem "logstash-output-elasticsearch"
        gem "logstash-output-file"
        gem "logstash-output-graphite"
        gem "logstash-output-http"
        gem "logstash-output-irc"
        gem "logstash-output-kafka", "~> 5"
        gem "logstash-output-nagios"
        gem "logstash-output-null"
        gem "logstash-output-pagerduty"
        gem "logstash-output-pipe"
        gem "logstash-output-rabbitmq"
        gem "logstash-output-redis"
        gem "logstash-output-s3"
        gem "logstash-output-sns"
        gem "logstash-output-sqs"
        gem "logstash-output-statsd"
        gem "logstash-output-stdout"
        gem "logstash-output-tcp"
        gem "logstash-output-udp"
        gem "logstash-output-webhdfs"
        gem "logstash-filter-dissect"
        gem "logstash-input-dead_letter_queue"
```

I have tried bundle install and also tried to change the PATH but it doesnt recognise it as internal variable, don't know how to fix this.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: can you add your Gemfile to the question?

Comment: Yes, just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you must install the logstash input plugin by running

> bin/logstash-plugin install logstash-input-jdbc

And also If it does not help,
try

> Java::com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

instead of the

> com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

for the jdbc_driver_class. I had a same kind of problem with oracle when I did not use the

> Java::

before the oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver as the jdbc_driver_class.